# How create a local network on Android?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I want to create a network where my phone is the server, other phones can connect to my phone, and all of them can read or write on *a specific folder*, not all of my internal storage.

Recently, I was trying to use SSH (using Termux). I searched and asked about it on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). So, I could not find a way to use that. Is there any other way?

I don't know if I can do this with SSH or any other protocol. (I use Termux, and if there is any way that needs Linux, I will thank you for sharing it with me.)

I don't have a computer, so I prefer solutions without requiring it. I am ready to do it the hard way because it's the only possible way for me. Thank you.

Edit: my phone is Xiaomi Redmi 10. 128GB with 4GB RAM.

Comment: Note that if your phone is in Hotspot mode opened ports will not be accessible by the clients (unrooted device). So accessing a port on you phone only works if you are connected as client to a Wifi e.g. operated by a Wifi router. What Android version is running on your phone?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. I have Xiaomi Redmi 10. And i use a modem , there's no problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several protocols you could use for this. I have not used any of these apps.

### File Transfer Protocol ("FTP")

This is a pretty early Internet protocol, but it still works.

- [Banana Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.ftpserver&hl=en&gl=US)'s FTP server was updated this month, and is free.
- [PowerFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.medialux.powerftp&hl=en&gl=US) is both client and server, and updated in August.

### Secure File Transfer Protocol ("SFTP")

This is essentially "FTP over SSH".

[Banana Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver&hl=en&gl=US) offers a server for this, also updated this month. There are several SFTP clients on the Play Store:

- [Terminus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client&hl=en&gl=US) was updated this month.
- [Mobile SFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobilesftp.feng.gao&hl=en&gl=US) was also updated this month.